# How to delete any folder using Python over windows Operating system

Tags: python-3.x, windows, permission-denied

I have tried to delete a particular folder using python. But its always throws an error as access denied. I used several methods, unfortunately, I didn't get solution from there.

First I use this code to remove an empty directory or folder.

> I got `PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'my files\\dss'` this error.

```
import os 

path = 'my files/dss'
os.remove(path)
```

Later, I tried,

```
import os

path = 'my files/dss'
os.rmdir(path)
```

> again I got error and that is `PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'my files\\dss'`.
> I know os.rmdir() use when the folder is empty. I was use an if block and check directory whether empty or not, to prevent an error, while using 'os.rmdir()'

Lastly, I also tried this method,

```
import shutil

path = 'my files/dss'
shutil.rmtree(path)
```

I have got an error as Access is denied. I cannot understand How I overcome this problem.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "D:\pyWork\clear_and_clutter\fileoperation.py", line 161, in <module>
> shutil.rmtree(Path)
> File "C:\Python311\Lib\shutil.py", line 758, in rmtree
> return _rmtree_unsafe(path, onerror)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "C:\Python311\Lib\shutil.py", line 625, in _rmtree_unsafe
> onerror(os.rmdir, path, sys.exc_info())
> File "C:\Python311\Lib\shutil.py", line 623, in _rmtree_unsafe
> os.rmdir(path)
> PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'my files\dss'

I also use another method, like I went to properties of that file, and uncheck **Read Only**, still its not working. [properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VLKc.png)

Comment: If you are working on Windows, then you should be using \\, (the first backslash escapes the second), and not /.

Comment: Thank you sir for your kind reply. You are right. Unfortunately, two backslashes comes while error throws. And, in my code I used only single slash - '/'.

Comment: @Tareq Can you clarify: when you say `Unfortunately, two backslashes comes while error throws`, does that mean that when you use two backslashes, you get an error? And if so, what's the error?

Comment: No no, its not like that, double backslash shows on output only while error occurred, on the other hand I used slash on code.